# Oracle + ASM + LVM + Pacemarker

Tags: oracle, cluster-computing, lvm, pacemaker

I need to create a cluster with RedHat7 (pacemarker) for a Oracle database. The DBA say that need to use Oracle ASM for manage disks but Cluster need use LVM. Can I use LVM and ASM ?

Comment: What happened when you googled for "oracle asm lvm"?

Comment: I do not find any result for my question

Answer (score 0):

Event though I don't like to just quote text from the documentation as an "answer" I think it does the job in this case :)

> "Although you can specify a logical volume as a device in an Oracle
>   ASM disk group, Oracle does not recommend their use because it adds a
>   layer of complexity that is unnecessary with Oracle ASM. In addition,
>   Oracle RAC requires a cluster logical volume manager in case you
>   decide to use a logical volume with Oracle ASM and Oracle RAC." http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/CWLIN/storage.htm#CFACJAGB

You have three choices:

- don't use LVM use ASM instead
- don't use ASM use LVM instead
- ignore Oracle's recommendation and use LVM + ASM.

If you don't plan on installing a RAC, I see the need of using ASM.

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Comment: We will not use RAC (very expensive). And we need use LVM for RedHat cluster solution. So I think that the way is not use ASM.